# Keep me logged in php function using modal dialog login form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to do is when I check the checkbox button in my dialog box the email and the password that I've typed on it will be saved and redirect to profile.php.

My problem is it doesn't work and I have an error in the inputbox that says:

> Undefined index: unm and  Undefined index: pwd

Does anyone here can help me with my problem?

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['chkbox'])) {
        setcookie("unm",$_POST['email'],time()+3600);
        setcookie("pwd",$_POST['password'],time()+3600);
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location="profile.php";
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</a>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h5 class="modal-title">PLEASE ENTER YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS AND PASSWORD TO LOG IN.</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
                                                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['unm'] ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email Address..." />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                                                    <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['pwd'] ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password..." />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="staylogged" class="checkbox-inline" />
                                                <label>  &nbsp; Keep me logged in</label>  &nbsp; <b>|</b>
                                                <a href="" style="text-decoration:none">  &nbsp; Forgot your password?</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                                <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</button>
                                                <button type="button" id="show_signup_md" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Register</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You are getting undefined index errors because your form has `$_COOKIE['unm']`, but if the cookie is not yet set, that index (`unm`) is not yet set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if $_COOKIE['pwd'] or $_COOKIE['unm'] set at the html before echo them:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['pwd']) && !empty($_COOKIE['pwd'])){
    $pwd = $_COOKIE['pwd'];
}else{
    $pwd = '';
}
//same for unm 

if(isset($_COOKIE['unm']) && !empty($_COOKIE['unm'])){
    $unm = $_COOKIE['unm'];
}else{
    $unm = '';
}
```

then the input should be :

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $unm ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email Address..." />                                    
 //same for pass 
<input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $pwd ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password..." />
```

Next thing don't store user details at cookies! . if do so use hashed string.